# How to insert a page break at the end of a page

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I need to insert a page break at the end of the first page. Below is the selection.  I am trying to insert a new page, then insert the page break at the end of that page.

```
object what = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;
object which = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute;
object count = 1; //change this number to specify the start of a different page

oWord.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count, ref oMissing);

oWord.Selection.InsertNewPage();
```

Comment: `what` and `which` are awesome variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page break can be added to a Word document in the following way:

```
string pageBreak = "\xC";
```

or by

```
string pageBreak= "\f";
```

Comment: @sharpiee, need any other help?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following after inserting the new page:

```
oWord.Selection.InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);
```